# How do I launch a python package using portable python.exe? It won't find the package

Tags: python, pip, package

I have a python package that I launch using system python from CMD like this:

```
python -m packagename.scriptname
```

However, I need this to work using embedded/portable Python, but I always get "Error while finding module specification".

I have already tried setting PYTHONPATH to the folder the package is in, which didn't work. Neither does using an absolute path (like "-m D:/packages/thepackage/packagename.scriptname").

How do I run this package using portable python?

Answer (score 0):

I would try installing the package locally to the embedded python. For example `/path/to/embedded/python.exe -m pip install /path/to/packagename`?

Comment: This is not an option for me as I would like to run the package without modifying the python installation.